# Enterprise Architect document creation - filter

Tags: templates, enterprise-architect

Enterprise Architect was introduced to me only today, and i also got a task related to document generation, which should be done as soon as possible.

I have to write a template for doc generation, and this template should do some filtering or conditioning on a specific element.
From a closer look: I have an element, which has a special field {Element.SpecialField}, that can hold values of true or fase. If the field's value is true, then the field's name should be generated into the doc, else nothing.

Which is the easiest way to do this? Scripting or selector/fragment filters? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The generated document should look something like this:

![EA Document]: http://s29.postimg.org/68edfthdz/EA_doc.jpg

The cells containing question marks are the specific element values I mentioned above the EDIT section.

There are three element fields: TagValue_X, TagValue_Y and TagValue_Z.
They can be true or "" (empty string) individually.

But in the table cell I don't want to see their values, but the names of the fields separated by commas. For example: if

```
{Element.valueOf(X)} == true AND {Element.valueOf(Y)} == "" AND {Element.valueOf(Z)} == true
```

, then the cell should contain "X, , Z".

**EDIT 2:** To Geert's answer.

The following script works well, when I want to to search in the Model (CTRL+ALT+A in EA 12):

```
SELECT t_objectproperties.Property FROM t_object, t_objectproperties
WHERE t_objectproperties.Value='True'
AND t_objectproperties.Property='X'
AND t_object.Object_ID = t_objectproperties.Object_ID
```

How should I modify this to apply it as a Custom Query in the fragment template? I tried some queries like this, but they never returned anything. Probably this is a basic conceptual misunderstanding issue from me...

```
SELECT t_objectproperties.Property AS SomeQuery
FROM t_objectproperties
WHERE t_objectproperties.Value='True'
AND t_objectproperties.Property='X'
AND t_objectproperties.Object_ID = #OBJECTID#
```

TemplateMain:

```
package>
element>
{Template - TemplateFragment}
<element
<package
```

TemplateFragment:

```
custom>
{SomeQuery}
<custom
```

I suppose the fragment template should be inserted into the element section.

Comment: What's easiest depends on too many other factors to give a good answer. If you can describe the specific problem you're having we can probably help you solve that.

Comment: Hi! I edited the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create an SQL fragment.

Using SQL you can return exactly the fields you need based on the PackageID passed to the template fragment.

Check the learning center (Alt-F1) for a step-by-step guide on creating SQL fragments.

Comment: The Learning Center seems useful, but not really detailed about this topic. I added an EDIT 2 section for my original question.

Comment: I checked your edit, but it seems to be like that should work. Did you paste the query in the Custom Query section of the template fragment? And selcted Custom SQL as Template Fragment Type?

Comment: There are two documents in the Learning Centre specifically about SQL fragments: Enterprise Architect|Reporting|RTF Template Fragments|Create a SQL based Fragment (1 and 2)

Comment: I checked the mentioned docs, therefore I could create the stuff presented in EDIT 2.  

What finally worked for me is the following:


`SELECT t_objectproperties.Property AS SomeQuery
FROM t_object, t_objectproperties
WHERE t_object.Package_ID = #PACKAGEID#
AND t_objectproperties.Object_ID = #OBJECTID#
AND t_objectproperties.Value='True'
AND t_objectproperties.Property='X'`


So I added t_object and #PACKAGEID# to the selection. Sorry for the poor comment formatting.